# Netbeans - Entity Classes from DB + JSF Pages not working properly

Tags: jsf, netbeans, code-generation, netbeans-8

With Netbeans 8.2, after generating Entity classes (Model + Facade + Controller) from a database and JSF Pages from these Classes, I have a problem on viewing / editing / deleting the entries.

Everything was successfully generated, but the action links (View, Edit, Destroy) in the List.xhtml view aren't working as expected.
Instead of selecting the clicked entry, it takes the first entry of the list. In another words, wherever I click on the list, I always get to the first entry for viewing, editing or deleting.

A link links is like : `<h:commandLink action="#{pictureController.prepareView}" value="#{bundle.ListPictureViewLink}"/>`

And the pictureController.prepareView is like :

```
public String prepareView() {
        current = (Picture) getItems().getRowData();
        selectedItemIndex = pagination.getPageFirstItem() + getItems().getRowIndex();
        return "View";
    }
```

After some debugging, I realized the "current" variable is null and the selectedItemIndex is 0, so it makes sense that it's not the selected row but I don't understand why.

I thought the DataModel was managing this. For info I am new to Java, JSF and all these technologies.

Comment: I did some tutorials before and I didn't have any problem, but this is a project I must do with Netbeans and the code generation for university, so take it easy.
I did the debug and the debug just says the current is null. The DataModel is what is pointed by getRowData(), I don't really know what it is, it's Netbeans generated code

Comment: The teacher did help us on this project, but classes are over and now I'm on my own. This seems to be a Netbeans code generation related problem. I asked here to see if someone else had the problem and could help, don't be so agressive please...